# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason

Tags: ios

I am using search bar in collection,when I am doing filter text I got the error like

```
` Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 2147483647 beyond bounds [0 .. 37]'
*** First throw call stack:
```

`
Here is my code

```
- (void)filterListForSearchText:(NSString *)searchText
{

    for (NSString *title in _arrayCCName) {
       NSRange nameRange = [title rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
        if (nameRange.location != NSNotFound) {
            [_searchResultName addObject:title];
        }
    }


    for (int i=0; i<_searchResultName.count; i++) {

        NSString *str=[ObjCls objectAtIndex:i];

        NSInteger index=[_searchResultName indexOfObject:str];
        [_searchResultDeignation addObject:[_arrayCCDesignation objectAtIndex:index]];
        [_searchResultProfilePicture addObject:[_arrayCCProfilePicture objectAtIndex:index]];
        [_searchResultFamilyPicture addObject:[_arrayCCFamilyPicture objectAtIndex:index]];
        NSLog(@"array index is %ld",(long)index);

    }
}
-(void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{

    SEARCHBAR.showsCancelButton=NO;
    [self.view endEditing:YES];

}
```

I got above error please help me how it is solve?

Comment: Add an exception breakpoint. From the Mian Menu Debug:Breakpoints:Create Exception Breakpoint. Run the app to get the breakpoint. When you hit the exception breakpoint **click debug continue** a couple of times and you will get a backtrace and more error info. Post that and an exact copy of Xcode/Debugger messages.

Comment: maybe your `index` is greater then `_arrayCCDesignation.count` or `_arrayCCProfilePicture.count` or `_arrayCCFamilyPicture.count`

Comment: nsmuttablearray object name

Comment: thanks for your suggestions, and i get my mistake

Comment: NSString *str=[ObjCls objectAtIndex:i];
here is the mistake,i replaced _searchCCName with objcls and _arrarCCName with _searchCCName

Answer (score 0):

Simply means that the value of index is greater than the size of array at some point. When using **[array objecAtIndex:index]**, index must be less than array.count.

Answer (score 0):

These lines here....

```
    NSInteger index=[_searchResultName indexOfObject:str];
    [_searchResultDeignation addObject:[_arrayCCDesignation objectAtIndex:index]];
    [_searchResultProfilePicture addObject:[_arrayCCProfilePicture objectAtIndex:index]];
    [_searchResultFamilyPicture addObject:[_arrayCCFamilyPicture objectAtIndex:index]];
    NSLog(@"array index is %ld",(long)index);
```

You are assuming that the indexOfObject actually finds something. What happens if the `str` doesn't exist

Taken from the documentation....

Declaration
OBJECTIVE-C
- (NSUInteger)indexOfObject:(id)anObject
Parameters
anObject
An object.
Return Value
The lowest index whose corresponding array value is equal to anObject. If none of the objects in the array is equal to anObject, returns **NSNotFound**.